# Two similar transactions - yet one throws underflow error

Tags: transactions, uniswap, ethers.js, overflow

I have two seemingly identical transactions in terms of input data, yet one continues to fail with ‘ds-math-sub-underflow‘. The transaction that works was done through the Uniswap v2 add liquidity UI interface. The failing one is sent programmatically.

1. [Failing transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9cfdd760051ef8de82d5ff7b809b22f1d917ae84501ddcc7f83c878ff6b7b9e3)
2. [Succeeding transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x855b11f12c40ad6e36834529938edafdb5da2f12f8872b84b05da7fcb6624cca)

When looking into the input data both are identical apart from the deadline which of course is fine. The only other difference I was able to conclude on Etherscan is the 'Txn type' field which is using EIP-1559 rather than 'Legacy' on the passing transaction.

Is there any advice to remedy the failing transaction? The error log also shows:

- reason: 'transaction failed'
- code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION'

along with the generated tx object itself. If the full error log from the failed tx object is required, let me know.

[image: send uniswap add liquidity transaction]

[Attached](https://gist.github.com/projectacode/ea8784c1847f367705f644aef05a1d58) is the current code snippet of above image.

Cheers.

Comment: Your error is actually "ds-math-sub-underflow". Now this is a pretty vague error message, but with UniswapV2 I sometimes get it when my amounts are too small. So make sure your numbers are correct

Comment: Right, I should make that clear in the post. It’s weird seeing the input data being essentially the same yet one has an underflow error.

Comment: Remember that any UI representation of numbers takes the decimals into account. So `1` in website UI is actually `1e18` in the background code (if the token has 18 decimals)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Part of trying to get to the bottom of this if I still can’t figure what exactly it is, I’ll download the Uniswap UI and debug the tx object for the differences I guess. What else could be responsible for throwing an underflow error if the input data is basically the same? Any advice as to where else I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Lauri. Problem was just overlooked, no value of eth was supplied in the transaction, gasLimit was described only.